# Passing Parameters to Active Admin Table_for columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to set up a table_for in my active admin project which displays information based on methods I pass to it. I'm setting it up so that in the model, there is an array of arrays. The arrays within the array contain first the label, then the method meant to be run in the column. I'm trying to set it up this way:

```
panel "Acquired Shares" do
  table_for shareholder.acquired_shares_transactions do
    shareholder.acquired_shares_info.each do |section|
      column (section[0]) { |transaction| section[1] }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the code of the method which returns the array of arrays:

```
def acquired_shares_info
    data = [[:label, transaction.event.to_s], [:amount_of_shares, transaction.amount_of_shares], 
            [:share_price, transaction.event.share_price],
            [:total_price, (transaction.amount_of_shares * transaction.event.share_price)], 
            [:occurred_on, transaction.event.occurred_on],
            [:from_shareholder, transaction.event.from_shareholder], 
            [:share_transaction_action, transaction.event.share_transaction_action.name], 
            [:share_transaction_type, transaction.event.share_transaction_type.name]]
    return data 
end
```

This is all is meant to create a column for each label and method I specify in the array. However, I am stuck on how to pass the labels and methods from the array into the column for the table. The way that I try here keeps throwing the error "No block given" on the array. Anyone have ideas on how to set this up?
Thank you!

Comment: can't you do something like this `column "#{section[0]}" do ; section[1]; end` ?

Answer (score 0):

Defer evaluation of the method by wrapping it in a proc. Pass the proc as the last parameter instead of specifying a block, Ruby will substitute it for you.

```
data = [[:label, proc { |transaction| transaction.event.to_s }], ...
...
  column section[0], section[1]
...
```